# How do I connect to two different Networks with the Same SSID but different Keys

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

At my work they have a  Wireless network and At school it has the Same SSID, the Keys are different but everything else is the same. How Do I save two profiles with the Same stats except the SSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your software can tell the difference by using the BSSID (hardware address), which is almost certainly different.  Your default Windows 7 configuration may not support doing that, though.

Comment: What Software doesn support BSSID?

Comment: I didn't say there was software that didn't, I said the stuff you have may not.  I don't know